# Tensorflow: tf.control_dependencies does not work as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to accomplish the following: I have a (A,B,C,D) shaped tensor, say, (110,14,14,32). In the computation graph, I want to obtain the shape of this tensor as another tensor and want to set the first dimension to a another value, say 250. (250 will come from a `tf.placeholder`). Then I will use this in a `tf.scatter_nd` call. To test this, I have implemented the following:

```
batch_size = 250
sparse_length = 110
sparse_arr = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(sparse_length, 14, 14, 32))
indices = np.array(sorted(np.random.choice(a=batch_size, size=sparse_length, replace=False).tolist()))

sparse_tensor = tf.placeholder(name="sparse_arr", dtype=tf.float32)
batch_size_tensor = tf.placeholder(name="batch_size", dtype=tf.int32)
shape_tensor = tf.Variable(name="shape", trainable=False, initial_value=[0] * 4)
shape_assign_op = tf.assign(shape_tensor, tf.shape(sparse_tensor))
set_batch_size_op = tf.assign(shape_tensor[0], batch_size_tensor)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

with tf.control_dependencies([shape_assign_op]):
   with tf.control_dependencies([set_batch_size_op]):
       x = tf.identity(shape_tensor)

result = sess.run([x], feed_dict={sparse_tensor: sparse_arr, batch_size_tensor: batch_size})
```

In the code above, `result` returns with `(110,14,14,32)`. It acts like the second `tf.assign` operation in the inner `tf.control_dependencies` block is not executed. What I am doing is first getting the shape of the input tensor with `tf.shape` and assigning it into a variable, `shape_tensor`. Then in the second `tf.assign`, I want to set the first dimension of `shape_tensor` to an another value. (Since Tensorflow supports sliced indexing only for `tf.Variable` I declare `shape_tensor`as such). In the actual program, the real operations involing `tf.scatter_nd` will follow in the `tf.control_dependencies` block, I am just mocking it with an identity transform in this case. In order the following operations to execute correctly, I need to obtain the shape of incoming tensor into another tensor and set its first dimension to another value, in that certain order and therefore I am using the `tf.control_dependencies` s. But it does not work as expected. Are cascaded `tf.control_dependencies`  not supported? What am I doing wrong here? Or is there any easier way to implement this behavior?

Comment: I think you need to have `set_batch_size_op = tf.assign(shape_tensor[0], batch_size_tensor)` within the `with tf.control_dependencies([shape_assign_op])` block for that to work.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Why my version is broken then?

Comment: I find these things confusing too, I said "I think" because I was not entirely sure actually. When you are doing the second assign without the control dependencies `shape_tensor[0]` is the first element of the `shape_tensor` variable _before_ it was updated by the first assignment. So there is no guarantee of which assignment will run first. Note that `tf.control_dependencies` blocks affect only new operations created within them, so here the outer block does not really affect `set_batch_size_op`, which was created before.

Comment: This seems the most plausible explanation, thank you.